# No exception but status error while doing jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Here is my jQuery ajax code

```
      $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://example.com/request=r",
    dataType: "json",
    processData: true,
    data: {},
    success: function (responseString) {
        alert(responseString);
    },
    error: function (xhr, errorType, exception) {
        var errorMessage = exception || xhr.statusText;
        alert("Excep:: "+exception +"Status:: "+xhr.statusText);
    }
});
```

I don't get an exception but I get xhr.statusText as `Error`

Comment: did you load the script from the domain to which you make the ajax request?

Comment: not its hosted in another domain

Comment: thats your problem; its a same-origin-policy issue

Comment: What does the alert say?

Comment: Do you own cs-api-sandbox and/or does it support JSONP?

Comment: @Detect No i dont own it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're falling foul of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). The only client-side alternative is to use JSONP request type, if the provider supports it.

If not you'll need to write a server-side proxy to get the data (in PHP/C# etc) and then query that via AJAX instead.

Comment: @jade by server-side I mean on your own site. You then make an AJAX request to the local page which has grabbed the external data.

Comment: how do i do dat?i mean how to get data from that url without before using Ajax

Comment: Does your server support PHP/ASP/Python?

Comment: I don't know python, but if you google for how to make an external request I'm sure you'll find something.